# macbook can not access apache after edited username

Tags: macos, apache, file-permissions

I've edited my computer name in my macbook in sharing and made it `Ahmed MacBook Pro`

> Computers on your local network can access your computer at:
>   Ahmed-MacBook-Pro.local

and edited my username from Macbook pro to `Ahmed.K`  and now I can not access to any project in my localhost I always got .

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access / on this server.

I got this message in terminal :

```
Ahmed-MacBook-Pro:~ Ahmed.K$ apachectl configtest
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/thestudymachine/public] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/Users/MacbookPro/Sites/mostafa/front] does not exist
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified
```

domain name, using Ahmed-MacBook-Pro.local. Set the 'ServerName' directive 
   globally to suppress this message
   Syntax OK

I don't know what happened. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

To get this working you need to reset the permissions. First, open Disk utility and select the disk. Then click on disk-EHBO. If that didn't work you open terminal and type:`sudo chmod -R 755 [THE_PATH_OF_APACHE]`. Remember, i don't know if this is an production system. If you want to know more about chmod please check [chmod wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) and to calculate what you need check [chmod calculator](http://www.onlineconversion.com/html_chmod_calculator.htm).

Note: change [THE_PATH_OF_APACHE] to the path where the files are stored.

Comment: can you explain more please ?

Comment: What explanation do you want? You need to reset your permissions on your drive and/or directory.